# What happens to a losing player's cards in Exploding Kittens?

Tags: exploding-kittens, streaking-kittens

When a player draws an Exploding Kitten and cannot defuse they are out. Do their cards go back into the draw pile or discard pile?

So if you have a Streaking Kitten and an Exploding Kitten and you pick up a second Exploding Kitten, then you end up discarding 2 Exploding Kittens. So this means there are 2 less Exploding Kittens than number of people remaining.

So there is no clear winner?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens to exploded kittens?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/29366/what-happens-to-exploded-kittens)

Comment: I thought so too, but this question is about the Exploding Kittens with Streaking Kittens expansion.

Answer (score 6):

They go back into the Discard Pile.

> EXPLODING KITTEN
>   ... Unless you have a Defuse Card, you're dead.
>   **Discard all of your cards, including the Exploding Kitten.**

Since there are one more Exploding Kitten Card to start with than normal, there still can be a winner.

> STREAKING KITTENS
>   ... 6. Insert enough Exploding Kittens back into the deck so that the total number of Exploding Kittens is equal to the number of players - this is **1 more Exploding Kitten than normal** because the Streaking Kitten Card allows a player to hold an Exploding Kitten in their hand without exploding!

[Exploding Kittens Rules](https://explodingkittens.com/rules-ek)
[Exploding Kittens with Streaking Kitten Rules](https://explodingkittens.com/rules-sk)

Answer (score 3):

According to [the rules](https://www.fgbradleys.com/rules/rules2/ExplodingKittens-rules.pdf), you discard the cards, so they go in the discard pile.

> You must show this card immediately. Unless you have a Defuse card,
>   you’re dead. **Discard all of your cards, including the Exploding Kitten.**

Comment: So if you have a streaking kitten and an exploding kitten, and you pick up a second exploding kitten, you end up discarding 2 exploding kittens. So this means there are 2 less kittens than the never of people remaining. So there is no clear winner. ?

Comment: When playing with Streaking Kittens, you START with a number of exploding kittens EQUAL to the number of players, which is one more than usual. If someone with the streaking kitten draws a second exploding kitten and cannot defuse it, both exploding kittens AND the Streaking kitten enter the discard pile. At that point, the number of exploding kittens left in the draw pile should be one fewer than the number of players remaining.

Comment: If you change the question after an answer is given, the answer can become invalid or incomplete.

Comment: It seems like there could be a problem with the steaking kitten if someone uses the five card combo to take the steaking kitten out of the discard pile. If that player then explodes the deck could have n - k > 1, where n is number of players in play and k is number of kittens in draw pile,